# Appstore Uploading issue

Tags: iphone, app-store, bundle

I have set the base SDK to iPhone Device 4.0 and the deployment  target to iphone OS 3.0 in the "Targets info" section as well as the "Projects info" section found under the "Groups and files" section.All the certificates and mobileprovision files matches exactly.When i try to upload in iTunes using "Application loader".It's showing me the following error.

**"This bundle is invalid.Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the sdk"**

Please somebody help me to overcome from this issue.i have been spending days for this issue

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have set both in the "Release" configuration? 
The Target Info panel is usually set to the settings for the "Debug" configuration.

Uploading binaries with your settings should definitely work, I uploaded a binary with exactly these settings (base SDK iPhone Device 4.0, deployment target iPhone OS 3.0) just a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

I think Apple stopped approving any new applications below 4.0, so you have to set your deployment target to 4.0.

Edit: nvm I read it wrong. From Apple:

> "Make sure that your applications are
>   compatible with iOS 4. All new
>   applications and updates to existing
>   applications must be built with iPhone
>   SDK 4. In addition, the App Store will
>   no longer support applications that
>   target iOS 2.x.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? I believe you can still submit apps targeting 3.0, they just insist you build using the 4.0 SDK (which Sankar says they're doing).